# Как убить процесс не только лишь по имени но и по местоположению в C#

Tags: c#

Приветствую! Чтобы убить процесс по имени, я нашел такое решение:

```
string name = "chrome";//процесс, который нужно убить
System.Diagnostics.Process[] etc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses();//получим процессы
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process anti in etc)//обойдем каждый процесс
if (anti.ProcessName.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower())) anti.Kill();//найдем нужный и убьем
```

А как мне убить процесс по местоположению? Например одновременно работают два разных процесса с одинаковым именем но запущенные с двух разных файлов, я знаю местоположение нужного файла и нужно убить процесс, который запущен именно с него.

Comment: Откройте msdn [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и можно найти `Process.MainModule.FileName`

Comment: @nick_n_a, извините но я еще плохо разбираюсь в с#, напишите пожалуйста пример решения в моем коде. Благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как верно заметил @nick_n_a, узнать, откуда был запущен процесс можно через [`Process.MainModule.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename(v=vs.110).aspx). Но есть одно но: для `System` (4) и `System Idle Process` (0) невозможно получить `Process.MainModule` (будет вылеатать `Win32Exception`). Т.к нам это и не следует делать (ведь системные процессы закрывать крайне нежелательно), все данные процессы можно скипать. Вот что получилось в итоге:

```
public static void KillProcesses(string path)
{
    Process.GetProcesses() // получаем все процессы
        .Where(p => CheckIfProcessFileEquals(p, path)) // берем только те, в которых пути к файлу совпадают
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(p => p.Kill()); // убиваем каждый
}

private static bool CheckIfProcessFileEquals(Process process, string path)
{
    try
    {
        return process.MainModule.FileName.Equals(path, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase); // сравниваем пути, инорим кейс
    }
    catch (Win32Exception)
    {
        return false; // если MainModule недоступен - скипаем
    }
}
```

Comment: помогите пожалуйста разобраться с данной ошибкой - 
Ошибка CS1061 'Process[]" не содержит определения для "Where" и не удалось найти метод расширения "Where", принимающий тип "Process[]" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). killProcess Версия .net 2

Comment: @КиноТрейлеры нет возможности обновиться хотя бы до 3.5 версии фреймворка?

Comment: обновился до 3,5 и получилось всё :) Благодарю!