# Убить процесс, название которого неизвестно?

Tags: c#

Имеется процесс, название которого известно на данный момент и который можно убить!

Но если имя файла(процесса) изменить, то убить уже не получится.

Если заранее известно оригинальное название процесса, и его вдруг изменили, то как его убить (не по пути, путь тоже может меняться)?

P.S: Если имя процесса меняется, можно ли тогда сделать через модули? например прогонять каждый процесс и проверять по модулям или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как убить процесс не только лишь по имени но и по местоположению в C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683730/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b2-c)

Comment: ну просто море дубликатов с ответами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81

Comment: @Andrew, Да смотрел Я, это немного не то, если процесс неизвестен то как его убить? ))

Comment: В даном случае вопрос в стиле "а как найти программу которая мне нужна что бы запустить, если она может размещатся в любом месте?". Ответ прост: нужно понять по каким признакам можно вычислить эту конкретную программу и искать по этим признакам среди запущенных что бы ее убить. Вряд ли здесь найдется оракул который сможет тебе что-то детальное посоветовать на вопрос который задан в такой форме. Банально никто не знает что это за программу ты хочешь убить и по каким признакам ее можно выделить среди остальных :)

Comment: Может стоит  запомнить номер процесса вместе с именем файла в тот момент, когда он ассоциировался с еще не переименованным файлом?

Answer (score 0):

Многие программы имеют сохраненное в ресурсах внутреннее имя, можно искать по нему.

```
static bool ProcessCompareInternalName(Process p,string match)
{
    try
    {
        string internalname = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.InternalName;
        if (internalname.ToLower() == match.ToLower()) return true;                
        else  return false;
    }
    catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{            
    var allproc = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process p in allproc)
    {
        if (ProcessCompareInternalName(p, "program.exe"))
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
    }

}
```

Если у программы нет ресурсов с информацией о версии, ничего не остается, кроме как сравнивать по бинарным сигнатурам или считать что-то типа CRC32 (Windows позволяет открыть на чтение exe-файлы запущенных процессов, так что это вполне можно реализовать).

Comment: Не помогло, он просто не находит оригинальное имя.

Comment: а как сравнивать через CRC32 ?

Comment: @Anonymous с CRC32 я загнул, на самом деле вам просто нужно побайтовое сравнение. Сравните сначала размеры файлов. Если размер разный, файлы очевидно разные. Если размер одинаковый, сравнивайте файлы побайтово, пока не встретится отличие.

Comment: Я  даже не знаю как по байтово сверить файлы ( не очень долго в C# ).

Comment: @Anonymous https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/320348/how-to-create-a-file-compare-function-in-visual-c

Answer (score 0):

В папке, где запущена программа есть ресурсы, которые нужны ей для работы.

Как вариант, пройтись по всем процессам и зайти в рабочую папку каждого.

Далее, сравнить ресурсы между эталоном(искомая программа) и конкретной программой, так как вряд ли процесс будет редактировать свои ресурсы по причине того, что сменив имя `DLL` программа просто не сможет стартануть. Есть конечно лайфхак через манифесты, но если программа такое себе позволяет, то это какие-то вирусы.

Ну или Exe-файлы побитово сравнить между собой.